# Recorrer ultimo dato ingresado en PHP json

Tags: android, android-studio, webservice, jsonobject

estoy trabajando en un proyecto con arduino de sonido el tema que cada ciertos minutos se agrega un dato nuevo a la la bd, pero quiero mostrar en una vista de android el ultimo dato ingresado y que se actualice cuando se agregue un nuevo dato el tema es que tengo planteado una semi idea pero no me resulta no me muestra nada.
(el codigo es de un fragment que devuelve todos los datos en un RecyclerView ese si funciona)

```
public void Datosonido() {
    String Url = "http://localhost:82/list.php";
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.post(Url, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                String resp = new String(responseBody);
                cargar(resp);
                Log.e("INFO", resp);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {

        }
    });

}
public void cargar(String respuesta){
    LinearLayoutManager lm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    lm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    rc.setLayoutManager(lm);

    try {
        List<Sonido> lista=new ArrayList<>();
        JSONArray json = new JSONArray(respuesta);
        for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
            Sonido s = new Sonido();
            s.id = json.getJSONObject(i).getInt("id");
            s.nombre = json.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
            s.valor = json.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("valor1");
            s.fecha = json.getJSONObject(i).getString("fecha");
            lista.add(s);
            Log.e("AAAAAAAAAAAAA",s.nombre);
        }
        Adaptador a = new Adaptador(lista,this,R.layout.item_sound);
        rc.setAdapter(a);
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Registros Actuales

```
[{"id":"1","name":"A","valor1":"1","fecha":"2018-12-11"},{"id":"2","name":"Sonido","valor1":"709","fecha":"2018-12-11"},{"id":"3","name":"Sonido","valor1":"710","fecha":"2018-12-11"}]
```

con esto debería mostrarme el ultimo registro con todos sus datos en un fragment 
seria de gran ayuda un aporte con una idea para poder solucionar este problema.
intente en la parte del for del json hacer un for en vez de i++ poner json.lenght()-1 y i-- pero no me funciono

Comment: acostumbra agregar el código como texto para que sea más legible,

Comment: Poner código como imagen en las preguntas siempre es una mala idea, dificulta la lectura además de impedir ser copiado para hacer pruebas por las personas que quieran ayudarte. Siempre es mejor poner texto que imágenes.  Por otro lado si el problema no tiene que ver con php y tampoco muestra nada relacionado con php, no tiene sentido que lo pongas en el titulo y las etiquetas. Puedes revisar [ask]

Comment: Okay entiendo lo editare :)

Comment: podrás mostrar tu list.php

Comment: Deseas solo obtener el último elemento del json? @RenanMatiasMaturanaDiaz

Comment: @Jorgesys si deseo obtener solo el ultimo elemento del json, osea si se agrega otro dato me muestre siempre el ultimo

Answer (score 1):

Tendrás que modificar o crear un nuevo php.
Para mostrar todos los datos en un RecyclerView:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tu_tabla ORDER BY id";
```

Para mostrar solo el último dato ingresado:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tu_tabla ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
```

Si quieres conectarte a Mysql cada 5 minutos utiliza un handler:

```
List<Sonido> lista=new ArrayList<>();
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed( new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            lista.clear();
            Datosonido();
            handler.postDelayed( this, 1000*60*5 ); 
        }
    }, 0 );
```